# Cucumber variable parameter store separately

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

I have scripts written in java, Cucumber gherkin (intellij IDE) .

I would want to revamp it to store all input value in separate parameter file.

So that I can easily replace configurable value at that specific parameter file.

Is that best approach?

How does cucumber handle it, any additional library needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#using-qaf-cucumber-with-cucumber-runner) dependency that will enable this feature you are looking for. It also will add support to resource management for different environment as well as examples from external data-providers. Provided `user.name` and `user.password` in properties you can use it in step as below:

```
Given user login with '${user.name}' and '${user.password}'
```

Your property file (or xml file) will have following properties

```
user.name=testUser
encrypted.user.password=encriptedpassword
```

Comment: My machine not allow online download dependancy. Is there jar file for offline?